# How to add a mimetype icon in the home directory?

Tags: icons, home-directory, mime-type

## About the mimetype

I have created a mimetype and I want to add an icon for it. The mimetype is for To-do lists, it matches the `TODO` pattern and is of type `text/todo`.

I can confirm that upon creating a file named `TODO`, it shows to be of mimetype `text/todo`.

## Attempts to add the icon

1. So, I have linked a SVG file to `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/mimetypes/text-todo.svg` hoping that such file will be used as icon for my mimetype. However, it is not.
2. I proceed to run `sudo update-icon-caches ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor`, which runs quietly, but changes nothing.
3. I then run `sudo gtk-update-icon-cache ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor`, but I get the message:

> gtk-update-icon-cache: No theme index file.

or

> gtk-update-icon-cache: The generated cache was invalid.

upon running `sudo gtk-update-icon-cache -tf ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor`. This also, as you'd expect, changes nothing.

So, **how do I add an icon for my mimetype in my home directory?**

Comment: maybe cp /usr/share/icons/hicolor/index.theme ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor first before gtk-update-icon-cache action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have spent some rather lengthy time in trying to get this right, and I finally have.

### Creating the mimetype

First, you need to create a mimetype file and save it to your local `~/.local/share/mime/packages/` directory. The file can have a structure like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
  <mime-type type="text/todo">
      <comment>To-do list</comment>
      <glob case-sensitive="true" pattern="TODO" />
      <glob case-sensitive="true" pattern="TODO *"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Be sure that fields like `type` in the `mime-type` element tag match your desired mimetype, and the `glob` element tags contain a `pattern` attribute whose value matches the pattern of your disired mimetype. As you can see, your mimetype can cover multiple filename patterns through multiple `glob` elements.

In the case of my *TODO* mimetype, I needed the pattern to be case-sensitive, so I threw in a `case-sensitive="true"` attribute-value pair; if you don't need case-sensitiveness, this attribute-value pair is not necessary.

Once you have finished your mimetype file, save it with a convenient name, like `todo.xml`. (**Note:** the XML extension might be important.)

Now run the command `update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime/` and you should be done with it. This command will place your mimetype in the correct category directory under `~/.local/share/mime`.

#### Testing

You can test if your mimetype was parsed correctly by reading the `~/.local/share/mime/glob` files and by testing specific files with commands like

- `mimetype FILENAME`
- `xdg-mime query filetype FILENAME`

**These will only work after you've updated the mime database.**

### Adding the icon

In many linux distributions, third-party/addon icons are filed under the "hicolor" icon-theme, which is a fallback icon theme which other icon themes rely upon.

Add your icon to the correct directory under `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/` (according to the `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/index.theme` descriptor file that lists valid subdirectories), run `update-icon-caches ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor` and you should be all set!

Your desktop manager may require a restart to associate the new mimetypes with the new icons.

### Troubleshooting

If your files don't get the mimetype/icon you set for them, be sure to check very well the patterns in the mimetype XML file. Sometimes testing an obvious pattern may help you verify this.

Answer (score 0):

I test all method I can find (test many directory), and here is the right one I think. My system version is 16.04.

Due to the mimetype is OK for the freecad doc, I only setup the icon.

1. found mimetype name, eg **application/x-extension-fcstd**:

   ▶ mimetype '/home/eexp/文档/freecad/cigar1.fcstd' 
   /home/eexp/文档/freecad/cigar1.fcstd: application/x-extension-fcstd
2. found a suitable svg file and cp to here **/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/mimetypes**, and the file name must be **application-x-extension-fcstd** which just like the mimetype name:

   ▶ sudo cp ~/FreeCAD-logo.svg  /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/mimetypes/application-x-extension-fcstd.svg
3. update icon cache with **-f**, (here has the index.theme file):

   ▶ sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/hicolor/ -f
4. nautilus change file icon **immediately**.